Excel Arithmetic-related IF statement
I am tasked to find a way to compare several sheets with similar datatypes. They all have the same number of rows in total (payslips), but here and there, there are new payment types each month, ...
I figured an effective way of comparing these sheets, but I need one feature. Is it possible to write an if statement in the form of:
 =IF(A1=A37; ...) 

can be written as:
=IF(A1=A(1+36X); ...)

where X is natural instead? More like an arithmetic sequence rather than comparing every row in column A. Thanks!
I tried what I described above.

Can't make sense of what you say you want to do. What is the notation A(1+36X) supposed to mean? Access cell A_N where N = 1+36*X (whatever X is) or something else entirely? You can obviously compute things in the comparison section and in the results sections but they have to be syntactically valid Excel expressions.

Yes, as per the description related to arithmetic sequence. I would like to access all cells from a column that fit into a sequence of rows [1, 37, 75, ...]. You described it perfectly, but I still woder what the correct syntax would be to write this in Excel

What would be the next number in the sequence, and how many values might be in the sequence?  Where does the value X come from?

I'm not sure how you are generating your arithmetic sequence, as you've only provided three data points, but to return the values in those addresses, and compare it with the contents of A1, you can do something like:
=A1=INDEX(A:A,{your array of rows})

or
=A1=INDEX(A:A,{37;75;114;154;195})

This will return an array of {TRUE;FALSE;...} depending on whether A1 matches or not.
I much prefer using this method with INDEX rather than INDIRECT as the latter is a volatile function and, depending on how it is used, can significantly impact the performance of your workbook.

I think what you're asking is how to reference a cell with a calculated address. If that is indeed what you mean, the syntax is =INDIECT("*calculated address*").
So in your case:
=IF(A1=INDIRECT("A"&(1+36*X)); ...)
This builds an address by concatenating a literal A and the calculated row number.
